# how to set cygwin root directory?

Tags: cygwin

OK, this is a stupid question. But how do set correct root directory in cygwin? Is this something that should have been done at install time? It should be set to d:\cygwin but currently it points to c:\ and because of that \bin, \etc and other folders do not exist.
Thanks.

**Edit:** Looks like the registry key for rootdir has changed few times between versions (I assume). On the working box I have in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Cygwin\setup\" key "rootdir" that points to rootdir. On the non-working box I have completely different path: "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Cygnus Solutions\Cygwin\mounts v2/" and key "native" with value "d:\cygwin".

I think I will give up now. Thanks for the people who tried to help below.

Answer (score 12):

Check the registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup\rootdir`

On my box, it's pointed to `C:\cygwin`.

Comment: The command for that in `cmd` would be `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup /v rootdir`

Answer (score 8):

Ok, this is really late!
But please try the following:

```
cd /cygdrive
```

cygdrive is the cygwin/linux equivalent of my computer in windows

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! It should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The setup package asks to provide the desired root directory while running it. By default it's supposed to suggest using `C:\cygwin`, but if you had a previously installed Cygwin on the system in the past, it might grab the same path used the last time.

http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.c

Comment: Is it possible to change it without reinstalling it? It should be written somewhere like registry, do you know?

Comment: I've never had to do it myself, but it looks like it's not too painful... http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1998-11/msg00649.html

Comment: @Costa Did you notice that this is from 1998 ?